# Spring boot keycloak dockerization not work : Failed to load URLs from http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/heroes/.well-known/openid-configuration

Tags: spring-boot, docker, keycloak

I have dockerize my keycloak and spring boot application but i have an warn like :

```
Failed to load URLs from http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/heroes/.well-known/openid-configuratio 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

and an error like :

```
 ERROR 1 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception
```

Answer (score 1):

If both, keycloak and your spring application, are running inside docker, you can't connect to http://localhost:8180 from within the spring-container

Instead make sure the keycloak container already has a name (e.g. `keycloak`) or start it with a name `docker run --name keycloak ...`

Then use this name for the keycloak configuration in your spring booot app.

http://keycloak:8080/auth/

Please make sure that you use the internal (!) port of the keycloak container. I'm not sure about this `8180` port, but usually `8080` is the default port for keycloack running in docker

Comment: But it's work with my angular frontend application ... So if you see here my angular application will send the token to my spring boot backend app so i can access to the data.. So here if i use docker for my spring boot application it doesn't work.. But when in use my machine insted of docker it works. I'm sure that i don't have any mistake in the port or the API calls but still don't know why it not work

Comment: that make sense. Your angular application runs in the browser. To access Keycloak from there a request to localhost is correct. But your spring application runs java code inside the container. From within the container, localhost as Keycloak url does not make sense, you need the correct container name (`keycloak`) or another hostname/domain which is callable from inside

Comment: it not works too .. i set my container name to keycloak and stiil not working.can i get you email or something so i can contact you!

Answer (score 0):

Probably your spring boot application cannot access your dockerized keycloak because you forgot to expose the port to your host with `-p 8180:8180` flag

try to run your dockerizes keycloak with the following command:

```
docker run -p 8180:8180 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:12.0.4 -Djboss.http.port=8180
```

Comment: but i'm already try it and i'm running my dockerizes keycloak on port 8180:8180

Comment: but can you access the keycloak admin panel using http://localhost:8180? I'm also assuming that your spring boot application is running in your machine instead of docker, is this correct?

Comment: Yes i can access the key loak admin panel.. I already dockerize my angular app and it connect to my keycloak server to.. So if you understand the situation my front-end angular app will sent the token to the spring boot app to access data from it.. So when i dockerize the spring app and try that it doesn't work.. But it works when it's run in my machine